# how to look for a file name in another text file and if so extract information on the corresponding line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

In the code below I'm opening a `fileList` and check for each `file` in the `fileList`.

If the name of the `file` corresponds with first 4 characters of each line in another text file, I extract the number which is written in the text file with `line.split()[1]` and then assign the int of this string to `d`. Afterwards I will use this `d` to divide the counter.

Here's a part of my function :

```
fp=open('yearTerm.txt' , 'r') #open the text file
def parsing():
     fileList = pathFilesList()
     for f in fileList:
         date_stamp = f[15:-4]
         #problem is here that this for , finds d for first file and use it for all
         for line in fp :
              if date_stamp.startswith(line[:4]) :
                  d = int(line.split()[1])
         print d
         print "Processing file: " + str(f)
         fileWordList = []
         fileWordSet = set()
         # One word per line, strip space. No empty lines.
         fw = open(f, 'r')

         fileWords = Counter(w for w in fw.read().split()) 
         # For each unique word, count occurance and store in dict.
         for stemWord, stemFreq in fileWords.items():
             Freq= stemFreq / d
             if stemWord not in wordDict:
                 wordDict[stemWord] = [(date_stamp, Freq)]
             else:  
                 wordDict[stemWord].append((date_stamp, Freq))
```

This works but it gives me the wrong output, the *for* cycle for finding `d` is just done once but I want it to run for each file as each file has different `d`. I don't know how to change this *for* in order to get the right `d` for each file or whatever else I should use.

I appreciate any advices.

Comment: You should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The reason why the "for line in fp" loop is executed only once is because you're looping over one and the same file object each time - you're consuming all lines in the file without ever resetting/recreating the file iterator. Use "fp=open('yearTerm.txt' ).readlines()" instead to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to do some processing for each "good" line in `fp`, you should move corresponding code under that `if`:

```
def parsing():
     fileList = pathFilesList()
     for f in fileList:
         date_stamp = f[15:-4]
         #problem is here that this for , finds d for first file and use it for all
         for line in fp :
             if date_stamp.startswith(line[:4]) :
                 d = int(line.split()[1])
                 print d
                 print "Processing file: " + str(f)
                 fileWordList = []
                 fileWordSet = set()
                 ...
```